# Proxy NodeJS app to / and Wordpress admin and API on /admin and /wp-json with Nginx

Tags: node.js, wordpress, nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a NodeJS app which serves my main front-end ([ReactJS](https://facebook.github.io/react/)) which gets data from Wordpress using [wp-api](http://v2.wp-api.org/).

I would like to have both server applications respond to the same address. The Node application running at port `3000` to respond to `http://example.com/` and have all request for `http://example.com/wp-admin` redirected Wordpress's admin panel, and all requests to `http://example.com/wp-json` to WP API.

How would I go about configuring that in Nginx?

Comment: I don't think it's clear what you want to do.  Consider rewording the question, and including additional information on what needs to be proxied where, what works and what doesn't, and how it all needs to work in the end (e.g., what proxied where).

Comment: Not sure how to reword it. I basically want to have a NodeJS app to be proxied by Nginx to www.domain.com/* and have a Wordpress site be proxied to the same domain but www.domain.com/admin. Is it still confusing?

Comment: Yes.  You never describe what do you, and what does'nt succeed.

Comment: what do you, and what does'nt succeed?

Answer (score 0):

Extend the configuration of your node server (the second one) and add another location:

```
location /admin {
  # fastcgi stuff to run php/wordpress here
}
```

Comment: Would you mind editing to include how final code would look like, for clarity?

Comment: That is documented elsewhere. A good starting point for easyengine are the contents of common/php.conf and common/wpcommon.conf.

Comment: I read through wpcommon.conf but I'm not sure I understand how that relates... Isn't easy to just post the code of how that would look like?

Answer (score 0):

Use Nginx alias. it works fine for me. I have the same situation.

```
server {
    server_name app.domain.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http: //localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
    location /admin {
        alias/path/to/root/admin/interface/here;
        autoindex off;
    }
}
```

Comment: Based on your example, this is what I've been trying: http://pastebin.com/3we3XMat

But Nginx won't start properly, there's something wrong...

Comment: Thanks, but still Nginx won't restart with that code. There's something wrong, any pointers?

Comment: try sudo nginx -t  if there is any error it will show you.

Comment: if you wish then give me snippets of your code i will look at once in my free time.

Comment: The pastebin is exactly my code for Nginx. I use 'sudo service nginx restart' to restart Nginx, and it doesn't except -t. Sorry, I'm quite the noob with Nginx.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest namespacing the node server (note the `rewrite` line):

```
location /node-api {

      #strip the node-api and pass the rest of the URL to node
      rewrite /node-api/(.*) /$1  break; 

      proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }


location ~ ^/(?!node-api)(.*) { #all other URLs NOT starting with node-api
    #put Wordpress FCGI config here
 }
```

All you have to change in the application code is your API URL from `http://app.domain.com` to `http://app.domain.com/node-api`

Comment: Thanks for the response. But what I'm trying to do is to have the NodeJS app serving main front-end at `http://domain.com`, PHP serving the WP wp-admin on `http://domain.com/wp-admin` and API on `http://domain.com/wp-json//. Is this doable?